# Differentiation of trigonometry, can someone check my answer

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Differentiate with respect to $x$

$f(x)=(3x^{2}-4)\sin x$

Let $u=3x^{2}-4$

$du/dx=6x$

Let $v=\sin x$

$dv/dx=\cos x$

$f'(x)=6x\sin x+(3x^{2}-4)\cos x$

Comment: It's true,you can by this $$(fg)'=f'g+fg'$$

Comment: It is correct. This piece of information may be useful: the website www.wolframalpha.com is an interesting tool to check computations of this sort, the type that are mechanically fed to a calculator. In case you wonder about the nature of the steps or consider the correctedness of different paths to the same answer, we'll be happy to help!